# Not to paaken from the aruch hashulchan

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, halacha-theory

Someone told me the aruch hashulchan said not to pasken from himself (but to only use him to find Sources)

Is this true?

Comment: I find this very unlikely...he wrote it for the purpose of horaah. Why would he state his opinion if it's solely to present the sources?

Comment: Didn't the Shulchan Arukh also say that? Who actually says they want you to Paskin from their writings?

Comment: The aruch hashulchan may well say a rabbi can't pasken FOR HIMSELF. Is this Purim Torah?

Comment: Sure you not thinking of Igros Moshe? Even then it's not exactly what he said.

Comment: @user6591 no I am not, but what did he (Rav Moshe) say?

Comment: Along the lines of not using his seffer to pasken. Just to get an idea of the sugya etc.

Comment: @user6591 it is possible the one that told confused the 2

Comment: Are you thinking of the Mishnah Berurah? Because he says so in his intro. (Originally published in the beginning of vol IV; your copy may have it there or moved to vol I.) Also, the description of "I'm only bringing a survey of sources" is a sentiment both in the MB's sources and the original title page. His goal was to give a rabbi some feel for how the halakhah developed since the close of the standard Shulchan Arukh page with its commentaries, to help /him/ decide halakhah. See http://www.aishdas.org/asp/textualism-mb where I have a longer discussion and translations of the quotes.

Comment: Yeah I didn't mean you as opposed to him. Just a general possible mixup somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 8):

The implication of [his introduction](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F/%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%94) is the opposite. He says (or rather approvingly quotes opinions that) you can't pasken from the Shulchan Aruch because of its brevity, and you first have to learn the Beis Yosef. He then points to all the commentaries that were written subsequently to specifically address this gap, and then says the multitude of them create a new problem (or rather renew the old problem) of too many opinions. So he wrote his book to include the reasons and solve the problem.

Note though that regarding things that aren't practical (that is don't apply in his times, like Halachos about the Sanhedrin, etc.) he says:

> ט) לשלימות מלאכת הקודש הבאתי כל הדינים, אף שאין נהוגים בזמן הזה, כמו:
> דיני סנהדרין בסימן א, ודיני סמיכה בסימן ג, והמשא ומתן דביני נפשות
> בסימן יח, והדרישה והחקירה בעדים בדיני נפשות בסימן ל, וכל דיני הזמה
> בסימן לח, וכן דיני קנסות במקומות השייכים לזה. וכמו כן דיני כפל, ודיני
> ארבעה וחמשה בסימן שנ ושנא ושנב, וכל דיני רוצח ועגלה ערופה בסימן תכה.
> וגם דיני ערי מקלט נתבאר שם בסייעתא דשמיא.
>
> י) וזה דרכי בדינים אלו: מקור
> המקורות לזה דברי הנשר הגדול הרמב"ם ז"ל. ובמקומות שעל פי פירושי רבותינו
> רש"י ותוספות נשתנו הדברים מדעתו הגדולה, או במקומות שהראב"ד השיג עליו,
> או משארי ראשונים – הבאתי דבריהם בלשון "יש אומרים", וכתבתי המקור בשני
> חצאי מרובעים. ואם היה לי איזה דבר חידוש בזה, רמזתי הדברים בקיצור נמרץ.

To paraphrase, regarding those laws what he does is quote the Rambam and then add in "some say" when other Rishonim disagree. He doesn't really claim to be deciding anything.

Comment: Notably, he continued writing/ruling about issues which didn't apply to him in the extensive continuation of Arukh haShulchan: Arukh haShulchan HeAtid.